# Error Field doesn't have a default value in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have no problem in Laravel 5.2 but in Laravel 5.3 after create migration for user model, It shows me following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'family' doesn't have a default value` !!!

In Model user:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'family', 'mobile', 'address', 'status'
];
```

In Migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('family');
        $table->string('mobile')->unique();
        $table->string('address');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('reagent');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 6):

You should add `->nullable()` or `->default('somethingHere')` to fields which you send empty values.

```
$table->string('family')->nullable(); //this means that if you send empty value this field will become MySQL NULL
```

Or set default value:

```
$table->string('family')->default('default value here');
```

Than remigrate:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: no any problem in Laravel 5.2 ! Is there another way?

Comment: Do you have remigrated?

Comment: what do you mean `remigrated`?

Answer (score 5):

I found my solutions here is the link:
[Eloquent create says column has no default value](https://laravel.io/forum/08-08-2015-eloquent-create-says-column-has-no-default-value)

The answer is at the bottom, i just quoted the answer also

> imbhavin95 replied 8 months ago
>
> The reason this is happening now, however, is that Laravel 5.1 uses strict mode for MySQL by default.
>
> If you would like to revert to previous behavior, update your config/database.php file and set 'strict' => false for your connection.

credits to this man https://laravel.io/user/imbhavin95

Answer (score 1):

You can make it `nullable`:

```
$table->string('family')->nullable();
```

Or add some default value:

```
$table->string('family')->default('none');
```

After that you should back up data and run:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Then restore the data.

Or you could create a separate migration and just [change `family` to a nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns):

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('family')->nullable()->change();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I add `family` in `$fillable` after `password`

Comment: Thank you for help me, but in laravel 5.2 dont use `->nullable()`

Comment: @Ali it couldn't work in 5.2 without the error. When you'll use any method which uses `mass assignment` feature (like `create()` or `update()`), you'll get the error in both 5.2 and 5.3.